# How to eagerly inject the authentication manager of spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, autowired, spring-bean

I used spring security. And, I have made below settings for my spring boot project.

```
spring:
  main:
    lazy-initialization: true
```

So, All spring beans are lazy initialization.
In this situation, I want to early inject only the `authentication manager`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `@Lazy(value = false)` in your `@Component` that uses it. As per [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html):

> If this annotation is not present on a @Component or @Bean definition, eager initialization will occur. If present and set to true, the @Bean or @Component will not be initialized until referenced by another bean or explicitly retrieved from the enclosing BeanFactory. If present and set to false, the bean will be instantiated on startup by bean factories that perform eager initialization of singletons.

Comment: Which component uses `@Lazy(false)` annotations? I used `@Lazy(false)` for configuration implementing the `WebSecurityConfigureAdapter` class, but it didn't work.

Comment: You could try it in the configuration class and as well with the `@Bean` definition